# Split a range sequence into multiple string c#,linq

Tags: c#, linq

Not sure why question is being marked as offtopic, where as so called desired behaviour is included within the question post!

I am trying to write this program that takes two inputs: 
• a set of include intervals
• and a set of exclude intervals

The sets of intervals can be given in any order, and they may be empty or overlapping. The program should output the result of taking all the includes and “remove” the excludes. The output should be given as non-overlapping intervals in a sorted order.

Intervals will contain Integers only

Example :

Includes: 50-600, 10-100
Excludes: (empty)
Output: 10-600

Includes: 10-100, 200-300, 400-600 
Excludes: 95-205, 410-420 
Output: 10-94, 206-300, 400-409, 421-600

I tried to populate two Enumerable Range from include and excludes (after splitting,parsing ), but didn't find any efficient way of implementing this afterwards.

```
string[] _break = _string.Split(',');
string[] _breakB = _stringB.Split(',');
string[] res = new string[_break.Length + 1];
string[] _items, _itemsB;
List < int > _back = new List < int > ();
int count = 0;

foreach(var _item in _break) {
    _items = _item.Split('-');
    var a = Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(_items[0]), (int.Parse(_items[1]) - int.Parse(_items[0]) + 1)).ToList();

    foreach(var _itemB in _breakB) {

        _itemsB = _itemB.Split('-');

        var b = Enumerable.Range(int.Parse((_itemsB[0])), (int.Parse(_itemsB[1]) - int.Parse((_itemsB[0])) + 1)).ToList();

        var c = a.Except < int > (b).ToList();

        /// different things tried here, but they are not good

        res[count] = c.Min().ToString() + "-" + c.Max().ToString();
        count++;

    }
}
return res;
```

Any input will be of great help

Comment: Could you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @J.Doe Non efficient solution will be to have `bool arr[MaxRange]` which is initially filled with `false`. When you get `i` `j` range, if it is include range then assign `arr[ i up to j]` `true` and if that range is exclude list assign `arr[ i up to j]` `false`. the answer will be beginning and end of  every consecutive ranges of `true`s in `arr`.

Comment: @DominicEU code included now

Comment: @tchelidze can you please elaborate a bit :) and why would you call this an non-efficient solution?

Comment: @J.Doe Let me post an answer, since code written in comment is hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work faster than SortedSet trick, at least for large intervals. Idea is like:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Test
{
    using Pair = Tuple<int, int>;   //for brevity

    struct Point    //point of an interval
    {
        public enum Border { Left, Right };
        public enum Interval { Including, Excluding };
        public int Val;
        public int Brdr;
        public int Intr;
        public Point(int value, Border border, Interval interval)
        {
            Val = value;
            Brdr = (border == Border.Left) ? 1 : -1;
            Intr = (int)interval;
        }
        public override string ToString() =>
            (Brdr == 1 ? "L" : "R") + (Intr == 0 ? "+ " : "- ") + Val;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<Pair> GetInterval(string strIn, string strEx)
        {
            //a func to get interval border points from string:
            Func<string, Point.Interval, IEnumerable<Point>> parse = (str, intr) =>
               Regex.Matches(str, "[0-9]+").Cast<Match>().Select((s, idx) =>
               new Point(int.Parse(s.Value), (Point.Border)(idx % 2), intr));

            var INs = parse(strIn, Point.Interval.Including);
            var EXs = parse(strEx, Point.Interval.Excluding);

            var intrs = new int[2];  //current interval border control IN[0], EX[1]
            int start = 0;       //left border of a new resulting interval
            //put all points in a line and loop:
            foreach (var p in INs.Union(EXs).OrderBy(x => x.Val))
            {
                //check for start (close) of a new (cur) interval:
                var change = (intrs[p.Intr] == 0) ^ (intrs[p.Intr] + p.Brdr == 0);
                intrs[p.Intr] += p.Brdr;
                if (!change) continue;

                var In = p.Intr == 0 && intrs[1] == 0;  //w no Ex
                var Ex = p.Intr == 1 && intrs[0] > 0;   //breaks In
                var Open = intrs[p.Intr] > 0;
                var Close = !Open;

                if (In && Open || Ex && Close)
                {
                    start = p.Val + p.Intr; //exclude point if Ex
                }
                else if (In && Close || Ex && Open)
                {
                    yield return new Pair(start, p.Val - p.Intr);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strIN = "10-100, 200-300, 400-500, 420-480";
            var strEX = "95-205, 410-420";

            foreach (var i in GetInterval(strIN, strEX))
                Console.WriteLine(i.Item1 + "-" + i.Item2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ps: it can be generalized to work with any IComparable e.g. double or DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Built-in `SortedSet<T>` collection to do most of the work for you like this:

The `SortedSet<T>` collection implements the useful `UnionWith` and `ExceptWith` methods which at least makes the code quite easy to follow:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] includeRanges = _string.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
        string[] excludeRanges = _stringB.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
        string[] includeRange, excludeRange;

        SortedSet<int> includeSet = new SortedSet<int>();
        SortedSet<int> excludeSet = new SortedSet<int>();

        // Create a UNION of all the include ranges
        foreach (string item in includeRanges)
        {
            includeRange = item.Split('-');
            includeSet.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(includeRange[0]), (int.Parse(includeRange[1]) - int.Parse(includeRange[0]) + 1)).ToList());
        }

        // Create a UNION of all the exclude ranges
        foreach (string item in excludeRanges)
        {
            excludeRange = item.Split('-');
            excludeSet.UnionWith(Enumerable.Range(int.Parse(excludeRange[0]), (int.Parse(excludeRange[1]) - int.Parse(excludeRange[0]) + 1)).ToList());
        }

        // Exclude the excludeSet from the includeSet
        includeSet.ExceptWith(excludeSet);

        //Format the output using a stringbuilder
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int lastValue = -1;
        foreach (int included in includeSet)
        {

            if (lastValue == -1)
            {
                sb.Append(included + "-");
                lastValue = included;
            }
            else
            {
                if (lastValue == included - 1)
                {
                    lastValue = included;
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(lastValue + ",");
                    sb.Append(included + "-");
                    lastValue = included;
                }
            }



        }
        sb.Append(lastValue);
        result.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

[image: Application output]

Comment: brilliant :) thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So, you task could be separated to the list of subtasks:

1. Parse a source line of intervals to the list of objects
2. Concatinate intervals if they cross each over
3. Excludes intervals 'excludes' from 'includes'

I published my result code here: http://rextester.com/OBXQ56769

The code could be optimized as well, but I wanted it to be quite simple. Hope it will help you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const string Includes = "10-100, 200-300, 400-500 ";
        private const string Excludes = "95-205, 410-420";
        private const string Pattern = @"(\d*)-(\d*)";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var includes = ParseIntevals(Includes);
            var excludes = ParseIntevals(Excludes);

            includes = ConcatinateIntervals(includes);
            excludes = ConcatinateIntervals(excludes);

            // The Result
            var result = ExcludeFromInclude(includes, excludes);

            foreach (var interval in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(interval.Min + "-" + interval.Max);
            }            
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Excludes intervals 'excludes' from 'includes'
        /// </summary>
        public static List<Interval> ExcludeFromInclude(List<Interval> includes, List<Interval> excludes)
        {
            var result = new List<Interval>();

            if (!excludes.Any())
            {
                return includes.Select(x => x.Clone()).ToList();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < includes.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < excludes.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (includes[i].Max < excludes[j].Min || includes[i].Min > excludes[j].Max)
                        continue; // no crossing

                    //1 Example: includes[i]=(10-20) excludes[j]=(15-25)
                    if (includes[i].Min < excludes[j].Min && includes[i].Max <= excludes[j].Max)
                    {
                        var interval = new Interval(includes[i].Min, excludes[j].Min - 1);
                        result.Add(interval);
                        break;
                    }

                    //2 Example: includes[i]=(10-25) excludes[j]=(15-20)
                    if (includes[i].Min <= excludes[j].Min && includes[i].Max >= excludes[j].Max)
                    {
                        if (includes[i].Min < excludes[j].Min)
                        {
                            var interval1 = new Interval(includes[i].Min, excludes[j].Min - 1);
                            result.Add(interval1);
                        }
                        if (includes[i].Max > excludes[j].Max)
                        {
                            var interval2 = new Interval(excludes[j].Max + 1, includes[i].Max);
                            result.Add(interval2);
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    //3 Example: includes[i]=(15-25) excludes[j]=(10-20)
                    if (includes[i].Min < excludes[j].Max && includes[i].Max > excludes[j].Max)
                    {
                        var interval = new Interval(excludes[j].Max + 1, includes[i].Max);
                        result.Add(interval);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Concatinates intervals if they cross each over
        /// </summary>
        public static List<Interval> ConcatinateIntervals(List<Interval> intervals)
        {
            var result = new List<Interval>();

            for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < intervals.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (i == j)
                        continue;

                    if (intervals[i].Max < intervals[j].Min || intervals[i].Min > intervals[j].Max)
                    {
                        Interval interval = intervals[i].Clone();
                        result.Add(interval);
                        continue; // no crossing
                    }

                    //1
                    if (intervals[i].Min < intervals[j].Min && intervals[i].Max < intervals[j].Max)
                    {
                        var interval = new Interval(intervals[i].Min, intervals[j].Max);
                        result.Add(interval);
                        break;
                    }

                    //2
                    if (intervals[i].Min < intervals[j].Min && intervals[i].Max > intervals[j].Max)
                    {
                        Interval interval = intervals[i].Clone();
                        result.Add(interval);
                        break;
                    }

                    //3
                    if (intervals[i].Min < intervals[j].Max && intervals[i].Max > intervals[j].Max)
                    {
                       var interval = new Interval(intervals[j].Min, intervals[i].Max);
                        result.Add(interval);
                        break;
                    }

                    //4
                    if (intervals[i].Min > intervals[j].Min && intervals[i].Max < intervals[j].Max)
                    {
                        var interval = new Interval(intervals[j].Min, intervals[j].Max);
                        result.Add(interval);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result.Distinct().ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses a source line of intervals to the list of objects
        /// </summary>
        public static List<Interval> ParseIntevals(string intervals)
        {
            var matches = Regex.Matches(intervals, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var list = new List<Interval>();

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var min = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
                var max = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
                list.Add(new Interval(min, max));
            }

            return list.OrderBy(x => x.Min).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interval
        /// </summary>
        public class Interval
        {
            public int Min { get; set; }
            public int Max { get; set; }

            public Interval()
            {
            }

            public Interval(int min, int max)
            {
                Min = min;
                Max = max;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                var obj2 = obj as Interval;
                if (obj2 == null) return false;
                return obj2.Min == Min && obj2.Max == Max;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return this.ToString().GetHashCode();
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Min, Max);
            }

            public Interval Clone()
            {
                return (Interval) this.MemberwiseClone();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to solve this. The LINQ approach hasn't been discussed yet - this is how I would do it:

```
// declaring a lambda fn because it's gonna be used by both include/exclude   
// list
Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> rangeFn = 
    baseInput =>
    {
        return baseInput.Split (new []{ ',', ' ' }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .SelectMany (rng => 
                {
                    var range = rng.Split (new []{ '-' }, 
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                        .Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i));

                    // just in case someone types in
                    // a reverse range (e.g. 10-5), LOL...
                    var start = range.Min ();
                    var end = range.Max ();

                    return Enumerable.Range (start, (end - start + 1));
                });
        };

var includes = rangeFn (_string);
var excludes = rangeFn (_stringB);

var result = includes.Except (excludes).Distinct().OrderBy(r => r);
```